# How to run multiple testsuites using ant?

Tags: php, ant

I have some testsuites in my phpunit.xml file as follows

```
 <testsuites>
        <testsuite name = "messaging"> 
            <directory>tests/messaging</directory> 
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name = "media"> 
            <directory>tests/media</directory> 
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name = "dys"> 
            <directory>tests/dys</directory> 
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
```

And I run these test suites in build.xml in a target as follows

```
    <target name="phpunit"
                description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
            <exec executable="phpunit">
                <arg value = "--configuration"/>
                <arg path = "phpunit.xml"/>
                <arg line=" --testsuite messaging" />
                <arg line=" --testsuite media" />
            </exec>
        </target>
```

I've tried to run two of the testsuites this way. but it always executes the second one.
I've tried to write the testsuites in one argument with and without comma, but this format is not acceptable. 
How to do this?